# Rails Mailer TypeError on #deliver

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to debug this mailer error in `4.1.1` and can't figure out how to get more information on what to look into:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
  app/controllers/api/v1/contact_form_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

Here's the controller, line 5 in the error is the second line here:

```
  def create
    @mail = ContactFormMailer.contact_email(contact_params).deliver
    # ContactFormSender.perform_async(contact_params)
    render nothing: true, status: 200
  end
```

My mailer looks like this:

```
class ContactFormMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: ENV["CONTACT_EMAIL"]

  def contact_email(args)
    @from = args[:from]
    @body = args[:body]
    @title = args[:title]
    mail(to: ENV["CONTACT_EMAIL"], subject: 'Contact form')
  end
end
```

The error only throws when I call `deliver`, which leads me to believe that it's a `mailer.config` issue, but everything I've looked into for gmail seems correct:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV["DOMAIN"] }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings =
    {
      address: ENV["SMTP_SERVER"],
      port: 587,
      domain: ENV["MAILER_DOMAIN"],
      authentication: "plain",
      enable_starttls_auto: true,
      user_name: ENV["SMTP_USER"],
      password: ENV["SMTP_PWD"]
    }
```

I doubled checked all of my `ENV` variables and tried putting `begin rescue end` around my controller action to get more information on the error, but it just says it's a type error. Is there anyway I can get more information from a logger or something? The error makes me think it's a config setting or something that isn't being passed through, but I have no idea where to keep looking.

Edit: Here's the rest of the error:

```
 Rendered /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (28.8ms)
```

Edit 2: here's the real backtrace:

```
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `initialize'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `open'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `tcp_socket'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:551:in `block in do_start'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `call'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:550:in `do_start'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:248:in `deliver!'
 # ./app/controllers/api/v1/contact_form_controller.rb:5:in `create'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:595:in `process'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:64:in `process'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:501:in `post'
 # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/contact_form_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:151:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:151:in `block in run'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:221:in `call'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:221:in `call'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-rails-3.1.0/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:179:in `block (2 levels) in <module:ControllerExampleGroup>'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:321:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:321:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:380:in `execute_with'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:446:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:221:in `call'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:221:in `call'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-rails-3.1.0/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:321:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:321:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:380:in `execute_with'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:446:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:221:in `call'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:221:in `call'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:447:in `run'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:500:in `run'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:330:in `with_around_example_hooks'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:148:in `run'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:500:in `block in run_examples'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:496:in `map'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:496:in `run_examples'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:463:in `run'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:464:in `block in run'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:464:in `map'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:464:in `run'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `map'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `block in run_specs'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:53:in `report'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:107:in `run_specs'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
 # /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the stacktrace?

Comment: yeap, added it, I'm not sure how to read it though

Comment: That can't possibly be the whole backtrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SMTP_SERVER` env variable is nil.

I can consistently reproduce this error with:

```
2.1.2 :004 > TCPSocket.open nil, 40
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
    from (irb):4:in `initialize'
    from (irb):4:in `open'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/mauricio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

You can see the actual line where it breaks [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_2/lib/net/smtp.rb#L540-L542).

You should force your code to validate there's a value for all the env variables you need right at the config file instead of assuming there are values for them.

Comment: Yes! thank you! says I have to wait to award the bounty. For some reason, the env variables aren't making it from my `.yml` to my app, I hard coded the values and it worked. Strangely enough if I do `puts ENV['SMTP_SERVER']` before the breaking line, it will return the correct value but the connection will fail if it's not hardcoded. cheers!